# If statement giving parenthesis error in my triangle exercise

Tags: c++, c++11

Learning C++ and doing a basic triangle exercise.

Can anyone check my code if I done everything right and explain why I am getting this error: suggest parenthesis around ‘&&’ within ‘||’

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // enter 3 numbers for sides of triangle
    int a, b, c;
    std::cout << "Input three numbers: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cin >> b; 
    std::cin >> c;
  
    // check what kind of traingle it is and output result
    if(a == b  && b == c){
        std::cout << "You have an equalateral triangle." << std::endl;
    }else if(a == b && b !=c || a!=b && b==c || a==c && b!=c){
        std::cout << "You have an iso triangle." << std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cout << "You have an scalene triangle." << std::endl;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the stack! What compiler are you using?

Comment: Program compiles [here](https://onlinegdb.com/zs0QXhP5U)

Comment: That is not an error message.  That is a warning or informational message given by your third-party tool, or possibly the compiler.  The code compiles successfully.

Comment: It is a warning because without parentheses, readability is low because people have a hard time knowing which two conditionals the `||` is referring to.

Comment: When you have something like `a == b && b !=c || a!=b` consider whether you intended `(a == b && b !=c) || a!=b` or `a == b && (b !=c || a!=b)` and consider whether you know which way it operates without the parenthesis as well as future developers who might look at your code in the future.

Comment: The warning is because some compiler writer thinks you might not be smart enough to understand the code you've written. `&&` binds more tightly than `||`, so the compiler interprets `a && b || c && d` as if you had written `(a && b) || (c && d)`. That's the rule, and your code is correct. This is quite basic; some folks think it's confusing, but don't seem to be bothered by `a * b + c * d`.

Comment: As a mnemonic for memorizing the precedence of && (AND) vs || (OR), consider that AND is like multiplication (x AND 1 equals x) and OR is like addition (x OR 0  equals x). That said, explicitly parenthesizing is still a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

## The Error Messages you're receiving are a diagnostic that Clang can generate

If these are showing up as errors, you likely have `-Werror` enabled in your compiler options. You can remove that flag to stop promoting Warnings to Errors. Or, if you don't want it to issue warnings (promoted to errors) for what is (let's be honest) a pretty spurious diagnostic, you can add `-Wno-logical-op-parentheses` to the compiler options.

As to why this diagnostic is being generated in the first place: The Operator Precedence between `&&` and `||` is not always obvious, especially to newer programmers, and Clang is suggesting you expressly specify the operator precendence to make sure that what you've written is what you intend. So it's asking you to rewrite these lines like this:

```
if(a == b && b == c) {
    std::cout << "You have an equalateral triangle." << std::endl;
} else if((a == b && b != c) || (a != b && b == c) || (a == c && b != c)) {
    std::cout << "You have an iso triangle." << std::endl;
} else {
    std::cout << "You have an scalene triangle." << std::endl;
}
```

The extra parenthesis make the warning go away.

As far as I can tell there isn't *actually* a logical error in your code (the boolean logic behaves as you expect it to), and indeed, if you were to send this code to a different compiler, they compile it without issue. So this is really just a particular quirk of Clang.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is suggesting that you use parentheses to make your second `if` statement clearer/easier to parse.

In particular, you should group the `&&` statements within the `||` statement using parentheses. That is, change this code

```
(a == b && b !=c || a != b && b == c || a == c && b != c)
```

to

```
((a == b && b != c) || (a != b && b == c) || (a == c && b != c))
```

It's worth noting that this is a "style error"; the first form is not strictly incorrect code (indeed I was able to compile and run it just fine in the absence of compiler flags), but it's good practice to write it the second way.

If you pass the `-Wall` flag to your compiler (or more specifically in this case, the `-Wlogical-op-parentheses` flag) this will show up as a warning. Passing `-Werror` changes these warnings to errors, which seems to be the case here. It's good practice to use both `-Wall` and `-Werror`, since the compiler will then point out potential clarity problems like this and force you to fix them before continuing the compilation.

Answer (score 0):

This is sure to divide opinion, but I am of the ilk that you need to know the C++ grammar well before you attempt to push any code in production.

The fact remains that `||` has lower precedence than `&&`. And that should be as second nature to you as the precedence of the binary operators `+` and `*` ought to be. Emphasising the obvious with parentheses introduces noise and makes your code harder to read. I'd advise you to switch off that specific warning, and press on.

Note in your particular case though the second conditional simplifies to

```
else if (a == b || a == c || b == c)
```

as you have already eliminated the equilateral possibility. Again, some software houses insist that `if` statements are all mutually excusive in the sense that they can be arbitrarily reordered without the code breaking. Yet more opinion I'm afraid.

Comment: @Bob__: I certainly did. Oops. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: My experience is apparently very different than yours - rather than seeing not-strictly-necessary parentheses as noise, I see them as helpful documentation - breaking up a long expression into meaningful chunks.

Comment: @user888379 True, but it might be even better *not* to write a long expression, if possible, or *give a name* to those meaningful chunks.

Comment: @Bob__ Agreed - if it's possible.

Comment: Thanks all. I appreciate everyone’s effort in helping. :)